# Как получить размер файла и кол-во строк в нем Github API

Tags: javascript, github

Как через github api можно получить эти данные и возможно ли их вообще получить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно, очень легко. Возьмём, к примеру, следующий файл https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/src/lxc/caps.c

Он расположен в следующих подраздела: src/lxc/ и имеет название caps.c. Для того чтобы узнать более подробную информацию о нём, необходимо сформировать следующий запрос.

По схеме: [https://api.github.com/repos/владелец/название/contents/путь/к/файлу](https://api.github.com/repos/%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/contents/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%BA/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83)

https://api.github.com/repos/lxc/lxc/contents/src/lxc/caps.c, что в ответе выдаст нужную информацию:

```
{
  "name": "caps.c",
  "path": "src/lxc/caps.c",
  "sha": "1a6211a485053148166bd1082633b6c59f2d4b2f",
  "size": 7894,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/lxc/lxc/contents/src/lxc/caps.c?ref=master",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/src/lxc/caps.c",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/lxc/lxc/git/blobs/1a6211a485053148166bd1082633b6c59f2d4b2f",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lxc/lxc/master/src/lxc/caps.c",
  "type": "file",
  "content": "LyoKICogbHhjOiBs...uZGlmCg==\n",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/lxc/lxc/contents/src/lxc/caps.c?ref=master",
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/lxc/lxc/git/blobs/1a6211a485053148166bd1082633b6c59f2d4b2f",
    "html": "https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/src/lxc/caps.c"
  }
}
```

---

Для использования в bash-скриптах получить эту информацию можно напрямую с помощью jq.

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/lxc/lxc/contents/src/lxc/caps.c | jq '.size'
7894
```

### Обновлено

Всю остальную информацию по файлу можно узнать непосредственно исследуя само содержимое файла, благо оно передаётся в поле content закодированное в base64 (поле encoding). Пример получения такой информации в терминале:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/lxc/lxc/contents/src/lxc/caps.c | jq '.content' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' -e 's/\\n/\n/g' | base64 -d | wc -l
395
```

Либо, что проще, получить содержимое файла напрямую и также узнать количество строк в нём:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lxc/lxc/master/src/lxc/caps.c | wc -l
395
```

Comment: размер - да, а что на счет кол-ва строк и еще непонятной штуки (15 sloc)?

Comment: sloc - кол-во строк кода. вот тут есть ответ как получить https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository